# Does invoking a constructor mean creating object?

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class

When we create a Subclass object which extends an abstract class, the abstract class constructor also runs . But we know we cannot create objects of an abstract class. Hence does it mean that even if a constructor completes running without any exception, there is no guarantee whether an object is created?

Comment: Thank you for the question. even i had similar doubts

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Hence does it mean that even if a constructor completes running
>   without any exception, there is no guarantee whether an object is
>   created?

Simply speaking, a `constructor` does not create an object. It just *initializes* the *state* of the object. It's the `new` operator which creates the object. Now, let's understand this in little detail.

When you create an object using statement like this:

```
new MyClass();
```

The object is first created by the `new` operator. Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object.

---

Now consider the case of `Abstract class` and it's concrete `SubClass`, when you do like this:

```
AbstractClass obj = new ConcreteClass();
```

`new` operator creates an object of `ConcreteClass`, and invokes its constructor to initialize the state of the created object. In this process, the constructor of the abstract class is also called from the `ConcreteClass` constructor, to initialize the state of the object in the abstract class.

So, basically the object of `AbstractClass` is not created. It's just that it's constructor is invoked to initialize the state of the object.

**Lessons Learnt:**

- The object is created by `new` operator, and not by the invocation of the constructor itself. *So, the object is **already created before any constructor** is invoked.*
- Constructor is just used to initialize the state of the object created. It does not create an object itself.
- An object state can also be contained in an abstract super class.
- So, the purpose of invocation of `Abstract class` constructor, is only to initialize the object completely, and no object is created in process.

**See:**

- [Creation of new Class Instance - JLS-Section#12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

Comment: Is there a way to create an object of a class without using the new operator?

Comment: @minion No, there's isn't any way.

Answer (score 3):

> But we know we cannot create objects of an Abstract class

Right but JVM can.

> does it mean that even if a constructor completes running without any exception , there is no guarantee whether an object is created ?

The object is definitely created internally.

> Does invoking a constructor mean creating object?

Not always. you can invoke constructor using `super()` and `this()` but it won't instantiate an object. (but will just invoke the constructor)

```
class AClass
{
    AClass()
    {
        this(1); // will invoke constructor, but no object instatiated.
    }

    AClass(int a)
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AClass obj = new AClass(); // one object instantiated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: - Invoking a constructor never creates an object. It's the `new` operator that does it. So, your argument to 3rd quote is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Barring any exceptions, the abstract class constructor is only run from within the subclass's constructor (as the first statement). Therefore you can be sure that every time a constructor is run, it is in the process of creating an object.

That said, you may call more than one constructor in the process of creating a single object, such as `Subclass()` calling `Subclass(String)` which calls `AbstractClass` via a `super()`call, and so forth.

Comment: `it is in the process of creating an object.` -> No, it is in process of initializing an object. Object is already created using `new` operator.

Comment: @RohitJain "Each of these situations identifies a particular constructor (§8.8) to be called with specified arguments (possibly none) as part of the class instance creation process." ([JLS 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5))

Comment: @JeffBowman.. Well, JLS included the inialization of object in object creation itself. So, neither of us are wrong. Appologies. :)

Answer (score 2):

`Subclass == BaseClass + Extras you add in sub class`

Thus when you create a subclass by calling its constructor, there is a call to base class constructor as well to make sure that all attributes (of the base class) are also properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call the abstract class constructor as **a part of a concrete subclass constructor**. This is OK, since the **abstract class is extended into a concrete class** and it is an **object of that concrete class** that is being created.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the flow works when you invoke the constructor of your subclass:

1. Constructor of Abstract class runs --> the object is half initialized here.
2. Constructor of subclass finishes execution --> The object is fully initialized and hence completely   created here.

Comment: Note that Object are already completely created before the constructor is invoked.

Comment: @Rohit: I meant the object is half baked/ half initialized at this point in time :) I hope this is correct ?

Comment: @NiranjanBhat.. Hmm. Now it's quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke a constructor using `new`, a new object is being created.

Now, as you probably already know, every constructor of any subclass, either implicitly or explicitly, directly or indirectly, invokes a constructor from the parent class (which, in turns, invokes one from *its own* parent class, all the way up to object). This is called constructor chaining.

The above, however doesn't mean that multiple objects are created. The object has been created at the `new` call and all constructors working on that object are already handed an allocated area. Therefore, constructor chaining does not create new objects. One call to `new` will return you one object.

Answer (score 0):

I am completely disagree that the object for an abstract class can not be created and only jvm can does it in case of Inheritance even a programmer can do it a t times whenever or wherever he/she intends to do so by using the concept of anonymous class:
Look at this code and try it by your Own

```
abstract class Amit{ 
void hai()
{System.out.print("Just Wanna say Hai");}
abstract void hello();
}
class Main{
stic public void main(String[]amit)
{
Amit aa=new Amit(){
void hello(){Sstem.out.print("I actually dont say hello to everyone");
}};
aa.hello(); }}
```

Comment: Please don't post your your personal e-mail