# Why cannot ceate an abstract class instance but can invoke its constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, abstract-class, radix

I know we cannot create an abstract class instance, but I cannot understand why could use `base` invoke the constructor of the abstract class.

```
abstract class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Fruit(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Apple : Fruit
{
    public Apple(string name) : base(name) { }
}


Fruit f = new Fruit("Fruit");  // Coimple Error
Apple a = new Apple("Apple");  // Success
```

- Dose that `base` keyword just invoke constructors, methods, etc?
- What's the differences between **create an instance** and **invoke a constructor**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [`base` (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) first.

Comment: The *only* code that can invoke the constructor is a `base` call for a constructor of a derived class. Beyond that, I'm not actually sure what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601777/constructor-of-an-abstract-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: @judder Yes, he answered the question, but he did not answer why. And question 2.

Comment: @Soner Gönül I've been read this, but I want to know the detail about question 2.

Comment: Eric Lippert's answer answers your question pretty well on the linked question by @judder.

Comment: I dont have enough confidence to post this as an answer but pretty sure the difference between creating an instance and invoking a constructor is that creating the instance actually creates the object ie assigns memory and so forth. The constructor is 'a little extra' that bootstraps the instance into a usable state as defined by the programmer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the detail about question 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add that the fact that an abstract class may provide a constructor doesn't mean that it's not yet abstract.

By definition, an abstract class is a class where some or none of its members don't provide a default implementation, and derived classes must provide an implementation to these members. In the other hand, since an abstract class has some of its members as just *signatures* - the whole abstract members -, code mustn't be able to instantiate that class.

But if a derived class - either abstract or concrete - couldn't be able to call a base abstract class constructor, abstract classes would lack polymorphic constructors and there may be no way to initialize class properties or define a default class initialization code, even if that code calls an abstract method or property.

This is *why* a derived class can call a parent class constructor, even if the class is abstract!

> What's the differences between create an instance and invoke a
>   constructor?

We might try to address this question with a deep explanation with low-level details, but 
I feel that it's more a conceptual issue rather than a low-level thing.

If you want a summary, *calling the constructor* is a part of *class instantiation* process. It's a method which is called once the instance has been created and initializes the instances with custom code before any other code might use that instance.

When you use `base` keyword in a constructor to call parent's class one, you're just chaining constructor calls from the most derived class to the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Only derived class (e.g. Apple) can call the constructor of its parent (abstract class) with special `base` word. Constructor cannot be invoked (called) directly.

Answer (score 1):

> Does that base keyword just invoke constructors, methods, etc?

No, use it anytime you want to explicitly invoke the parent class' methods and avoid invoking a override in the derived class. Though `: base(...)` syntax is exclusive to constructors, usually you would call `base.method();`

> What are the differences between create an instance and invoke a constructor?

Creating an instance with the `new` operator does a number of things:

- Allocates memory for the object
- Initialises fields
- Then finally the constructor is invoked, which will invoke base constructor first if specified.

A more in-depth explanation of the order is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1882778/360211 but that should be enough to explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an instance with the *new* keyword creates a new object and returns a reference to the object.Invoking the constructor with the base keyword won't create a reference to the object(neither it will create an actual object), it will simply execute the code in the constructor.

Take a deep look onto this answer to for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/14453366/3789232

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question very well and it does not go into sufficient depth before giving a link to another answer